# Avoid several areas in HERE maps route

Tags: javascript, here-api

I want to avoid some areas in route using JavaScript API. I know, that Routing API contains such possibility [image]

I avoid some area  in JS API using that way[image]

Is it possible to avoid SEVERAL areas using JS API of here maps? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: don't post code as image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can include multiple areas separated by an exclamation mark, e.g.:

```
avoidareas=52.517100760,13.3905424488;52.5169701849,13.391808451!52.517000760,13.3700424488;52.5168701849,13.371308451
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn`t work. The response,which returned route is undefined, says the browser

Comment: I've tried this and it works for me. Can you copy the exact error message?

Comment: Oh, I've already fixed it, thanks. I used calculateRoute function in JS- that where i mistook,  i decided to use json, which was returned by Routing API link